# What is the first cardinal which has countable cofinal and greater than $\aleph_1$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What is the first cardinal which has countable cofinal and greater than $\aleph_0$? Is it $\aleph_\omega$? I'm not sure. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is $\aleph_{\omega}$. Let $\langle \alpha_n : n < \omega \rangle$ be a sequence of ordinals less than $\aleph_N$ (where $N>0$).

Since each $\alpha_n < \aleph_N$, we must have
$$\left| \bigcup_{n < \omega} \alpha_n \right| \le \sum_{n < \omega} \left|  \alpha_n \right| \le \sum_{n < \omega} \aleph_{N-1} = \aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_{N-1} = \aleph_{N-1} < \aleph_N$$

Thus $\aleph_N$ cannot have countable cofinality for $0<N<\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!

Comment: As far as I can see, your first $\:\leq\:$ needs the Axiom of Choice. $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Definitely. Choice is needed for this. For example, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/416218/462).

Comment: @RickyDemer: I usually presume that people use the axiom of choice when doing cardinal arithmetic unless specified otherwise, especially when there are $\aleph$s kicking around!

Answer (score 4):

Well, each (infinite) cardinal below $\aleph_\omega$ is either $\aleph_0$ (which is not greater than $\aleph_1$); or is uncountable and regular (by virtue of being a successor cardinal), but then has uncountable cofinality.  Since $\aleph_\omega$ has countable cofinality and is greater than $\aleph_1$, this is the least cardinal fitting the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!